# Will Kotlin's mapTo() overwrite data already in the Array?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to map the users from my database to an ArrayList of just their usernames, with the catch being that I need the first entry in the array to be empty, as the array of strings is going into a Spinner's array adapter.

So if I had code like this:

```
val users = ArrayList<String>()
users[0] = ""

dh.getUsers().mapTo(users) { it.toString() }
```

So will users still have "" in the 0-th position, or will the mapTo overwrite it?

Comment: If you had code like this, it would fail at `users[0] = ""` because `users` arraylist is empty at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code for `mapTo()`:

```
public inline fun <T, R, C : MutableCollection<in R>> Iterable<T>.mapTo(destination: C, transform: (T) -> R): C {
    for (item in this)
        destination.add(transform(item))
    return destination
}
```

As you can see, it uses `add()` on the `destination` object, hence it won't overwrite the string at position `0` and the result of the first `toString()` transformation will be inserted at position `1`.